# How to use OpenCV to process image

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Everyone!

I'm a beginner of ROS, and now I've been focusing on imaging processing on ROS, My robot is Turtlebot, and I use the kinect as the camera, so basically what I need to do is to find the changes in the same background, so I followed the tutorials and started to use Gazebo now, and I tested the kinect all is fine. So my question is, I am pretty lost since there is no example or demo for image processing on wiki, I am wondering what is my first step? and what should I do after that.

**If there is any good website for image processing on ROS to follow, that would be perfect! Thank you so much!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228407/how-to-use-opencv-to-process-image/) by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-03-07**:
may I know how you are getting images? are you using pictures or video stream? let me know about these and then I'll guide you for ROS and OpenCV image processing.

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-07**:
I got the video stream from Kinect, and I need to capture one pic using an order, every time I sent an order, one pic is captured. So what I need to do is to do the rest job upon the pic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS and OpenCV are two totally independent projects. All you need to do in ROS is to transform the image message into an opencv image using [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython). Once you have this image, you can do whatever you want with it using OpenCv functionalities. Check the extremely extensive OpenCV documentation and tutorials either in [Python](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html#py-table-of-content-imgproc) or [C++](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc.html).

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-07**:
Thank you very much! I know what you mean, It's like I need to write a node using OpenCV library to change ROS image first and I can do the image processing after this step in the node right? I prefer C++, so which means all of these should be done by cpp file is that right?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2016-03-08**:
I'm assuming you're using the image transport system and a camera to get your images. You'll need to use the ROS cv_bridge object to convert the image into a cv::Mat image. From here you'll be able to use the significant power of openCV to process your image. All of this can be done in C++

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-08**:
Thank you so much!!!! You saved me!